# How to use/create type of array in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, use-reducer

I have a react project, where I am creating a  store. Here is the  code:

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

import { Movie, MoviesAction } from 'types';
import { getMovies } from 'api/movies';

interface MoviesState {
  movies: Movie[]
  initialized: boolean
}

export function useMoviesCollection(): [MoviesState, React.Dispatch<MoviesAction>] {
  // TODO: Implement all action processing

  const movieReducer = (state: MoviesState, action: MoviesAction): MoviesState => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'fetch':
        
          console.log('ss', state)
          // return {...state}
          return { ...state, movies: action.payload };
         
        // return { ...state };

      case 'add':
        return { ...state };

      case 'delete':
        return { ...state };

      case 'rate':
        return { ...state };

      default:
        return state
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(movieReducer, {
    movies: [],
    initialized: false,
  });

  useEffect( () => {
    // TODO: Call fetch action
    
     getMovies().then((d)=>{
      console.log('g', d)
         dispatch({
          type: 'fetch',
          payload: {
              data: d
          }
      })
     })
  }, []);

  return [state, dispatch];
}
```

In my useEffect hook, I'm trying to call an API and then use the  Data/result to pass it inside the dispatch as the action's payload. Even though the API call returns the  type `Movie[]` of movie array but when I set it to inside the state, I get this error message:

```
Type '{ data: Movie[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Movie[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
```

The `getMovies` API call's implementation is like this:

```
import { Movie } from "types"

export const getMovies = async (): Promise<Movie[]> => {
    return require('../data/movies.json')
}
```

The  types/interfaces for MovieAction and  Movie are declared as:

```
export interface Movie {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    subtitle: string,
    description: string,
    imageUrl: string,
    ratings: number[]
}

export interface MovieFetchAction {
    type: 'fetch',
    payload: {
        data: Movie[]
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I have got wrong here? I feel I am passing the right type.

Comment: `payload: Movie[]` would be enough, instead of `payload: {data: Movie[]}`

Comment: The  type of `MovieFetchAction` has defined `payload`  with a `data`  property so I think that the  object he passes to dispatch as payload  will require him to have  a payload with structure: `{data: Moive[]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message state's the obvious error. Your passing `payload` with type `{data:Movie[]}` and in your `Moviestate`the type of movies is 'Movie[]'.

You need to chain call the data property inside your return to return the correct type.

Use:

```
return { ...state, movies: action.payload.data };
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to kick yourself:

You are writing

```
dispatch({
          type: 'fetch',
          payload: {
              data: d
          }
      })
```

when you should just write

```
dispatch({
          type: 'fetch',
          payload: d
      })
```

Incidentally, I would rewrite the whole thing as

```
  useEffect( () => {
    // TODO: Call fetch action
    const doFetch = async() => {
     const payload = await getMovies();
     console.log('payload', payload)
     dispatch({
          type: 'fetch',
          payload
     });
    };

    doFetch();
  }, []);
```

Which is (imo) more readable.

One thing you should notice here is the huge advantage that Typescript gives you.  If you made the same mistake in Javascript, you would not find out about it until some consumer of the store failed at some point in the future.

Comment: This didn't work because the type passed to the dispatch function is of MovieAction, here payload is an object and not a `Movie[]`. The answer below by @Haroon works. I just needed to set movies to the `data` attribute of the payload and not the payload itself. My bad. this is such a terrible question.

Comment: That's what I love about TS too.